# Suggestions to reopen a question

Tags: discussion

I asked the question "Is Batman a super hero?" A while ago and now I have altered and edited it over and over again to make it less opinion based.
Link: [Are there criteria for being a super hero and does Batman meet them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/is-there-criteria-for-being-super-hero-and-batman-meets-it)

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can change it so it may be reopened I would love to hear.

Comment: For the record, I liked the question and have already voted to reopen.

Comment: I've made a fairly chunky edit to refer to the DC website and make it a bit more of a substantive question.

Comment: The question has some good, well sourced and "definition" based answers; zero opinions. So I believe it **should** be re-opened.

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be reopened, both in its original form and/or with the latest edits I've added.

I think the question is fine. "What defines a **super**hero, especially when they don't have **super**powers?" seems an excellent fit to this site.

Comment: I second what you say. Also, another point raised re the question is that it will open up a slurry of similar ones; could you comment about that too perhaps (how would we avoid that? is it even a problem?)?

Comment: @Mooz - A "slurry" of relevant, on-topic questions isn't something to be avoided, it's something to be encouraged.

Comment: I agree, so often you see comments like "Oh here we go, there's gonna be so many x type questions" etc. But if the question is good, then there should be no problem for similar ones to appear.